# Given a random path in a Supersingular Isogeny Graph, which properties are relevants for belong to the cycle with minimal length?

Tags: elliptic-curves, random-walk, isogeny, algebraic-cycles

Random path in a Supersingular Isogeny Graph are used to find cycles. I want to know which properties are relevant for the path to belong to a cycle with minimal lenght. For example, the lenght of the path -maybe $log(p)$-, the types of the nodes, the types of the edges, the amount of nodes that contains self cycles, or the amount of nodes that are related given a particular formula, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.